# Laravel 5.3 web.php not working

Tags: routes, laravel-5.3

I'm web developer.
In routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
   Route::get('news/index', 'NewsController@getIndex');
});
```

If running http://localhost/project/public/news/index it has no action.
help me!

Comment: sorry, I found the error in the Controller(NewsController). Thank you for GiuServ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify? Do the controllers exist?
This code works good:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        echo 'one';
    });
    Route::get('news/index', function () {
        echo 'two';
    });
});
```

So the problem is with your controllers, or maybe with your apache configuration.

Comment: @Solomon I was just anwering to your comment when i saw your other comment above.
If it solved, mark the question as answered, maybe providing more details of what was wrong.